# System.Data.SQLite Error

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-2013

I have created a project on Visual Studio 2013 and used the System.Data.SQLite dll to access s3db files. On the machine I have developed it... it works. When I transfer the project files (and I have installed .NET 4.5 on the target machine) I recieve the following error:

[image]

Can anyone please give me a pointing direction ?
(I have installed the System.Data.SQLite)

Comment: Can you catch the InvalidOperationException and log its message?

Comment: Hi... Im not sure I know how to :-)